# How to use private keys from Android storage

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bouncycastle, jce

I'm trying to import a private key from Android system storage using next code:

```
PrivateKey privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(activity, alias);
```

where `alias` is retrieved using `KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias()` method. `KeyChain.getPrivateKey` doesn't return `null` but PrivateKey object contains wrong key (all its significant fields are `null`). I thought that the key is not exportable and tried to use it in the next code:

```
Cipher rsa;
rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] enc = rsa.doFinal(str.getBytes());
```

but got **NullPointerException** that comes from BouncyCastle internals.

The certificate with the key were imported from a PFX file using Android standard *load from memory card* function.

What I'm doing wrong?

UPD: I've tried to do the same with different RSA certificates and result is the same :(

Comment: Is privateKey not null?

Comment: what Android OS are you using? checkout (https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/source/browse/src/de/blinkt/openvpn/VpnProfile.java?r=77fc897870655adb63d53a72c72ee3e80b646d5a#403) for sample use of KeyChain.getPrivateKey()

Comment: A certificate does normally not contain the private key.

Comment: It could be difference between an RSA CRT private key and a normal private key. However, this question cannot be answered unless more details are given. Unfortunately, with the question being so old, I'm not sure if that's still meaningful. Current Android / BC may behave quite differently, there have been *loads* of changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code that is working for me perfectly:

```
KeyStore ks;
ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
ks.load(null, null);
keyChain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(ctx, certificateAlias);
privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(ctx, certificateAlias);
```

Comment: This seems to be  partial answer, I don't see how the alias is computed for instance. Code only answers are generally not considered all that useful. Why would this work instead of the code given in the question? The last two lines looks *suspiciously* like the code in the question.